# Angularjs + Phonegap anchor tag does not open web page

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I am using AngularJS and PhoneGap to create a mobile app. I've a HTML string with anchor tag, which I display on screen using `ng-bind-html`. But when I touch the link on the phone it does not open the web site at all. My intention is to open the web site in new browser window. The string that I am passing into `ng-bind-html` is :
`"<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system');\">www.google.com</a>";`

Also, Im using InAppBrowser Phonegap plugin for this. But this is still not working.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
<a href=\"\" ng-click=\"window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system');\">www.google.com</a>
```

[More... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/a](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/a)

**OR**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="a_id">www.google.com</a>

$( "#a_id" ).click(function() {
     var url = $(this).attr('href')

    var ref = window.open(url, 'random_string', 'location=no');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
                       console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
    } );
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
         console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);


    } );
    ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
                      //console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
    } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem to enable links in a twitter list which I was showing in my app.
I ended up using the following with a little help of jQuery:

1) use a filter to add a class to your links 
html:

```
<span ng-bind-html="myLinks | externalLinks"></span>
```

filter in controller.js

```
.filter('externalLinks', function() {
    return function(text) {
        return String(text).replace(/href=/gm, "class=\"ex-link\" href=");
    }
});
```

2) in your controller you can use  jQuery to add a click event to the links (I am using a timeout to be sure the links are loaded into the DOM and don't forget to inject $timeout in your controller)

```
$timeout(function(){
    jQuery('.ex-link').click(function (e) {                 
        var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();
        var system = "";
        if(device.platform == "iOS"){
            system = "_blank";
        }
        else {
            system = "_system"
       }
       window.open(url, system, "location=yes");
    })  
},1000);
```

Hope this helps.